# Wifi errors with Network-Manager on KDE Neon

Tags: linux, networking, kde, wifi-driver, networkmanager

I have a problem with Network Manager when i try to connect it with my hotspot a notification says :

> no secrets were provided

so i have to make my hotspot open in order to connect it,
but i face other problem after that, all the wifi disappear, i have to do this command to make it work again :

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

and i do this almost every time i reboot the PC or when the wifi is disconnected

is there anyway to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this "no secrets were provided" problem when I tried to connect to only one of many *wifi* networks I had configured in my laptop.

Still puzzles me only one network had this problem. It used the authentication protocol *PEAP*. Other than that, it was just like the other networks.

Anyway, what worked for me was to set an empty password to the wallet used by the network manager.

The procedure:

1. starting the "kde wallet manager" (it should come preinstalled with kde)
2. In the tab contents select the "folder" named "Network Manager". Just select it, there's no need to expand it.
3. Near the top-right side of the window, there's a button with the text "Change password". Click/press that button.
4. In the pop up keep both inputs empty and press the OK button. This assigns an empty password to this folder of the wallet.

Answer (score 1):

i think i fixed this problem, it has something to do with KDE wallet
first i disable KDE wallet and then i went to : Configure network connection > Wi-fi security and change store password from encrypted to not encrypted.
and now its working
so i believe there's a bug with KDE Wallet!